# Unable to open eclipse, start up screen flashes but never opens

Tags: android, eclipse

I just went to open Eclipse and it will not open. The start-up screen flashes up, then dissappears and Eclipse never opens. My task manager does not show Eclipse as an active application.

I downloaded a new version of Eclipse but am still getting the same issue.

Up until now I have had no problems with Eclipse and don't recall any issues closing it down the last time I used it.

The metadata.log error that I am getting says the following, although I'm not sure how to interpret / fix:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-01-04 16:42:46.844
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
```

Has anyone ever had this issue? Any thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: Look at the Eclipse crash log (usually in the root directory of your Eclipse installation); it's likely to give you a clue. Also look in `.metadata.log`. What OS are you on? What version(s) of Java do you have installed?

Comment: I think you are affected by any virus. Scan your PC fully with an anti-virus.

Comment: go to Task manager & close Task of adb Then try again.

Comment: @Ted Hopp, I'm using Windows 7, I have jdk-7u6-windows-x64 installed for Java.

The metadata.log has this entry
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-01-04 16:42:46.844
    !MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!

Any ideas what this means / how to fix?

Comment: Managed to use this information to fix it by looking through the eclipse wiki. See my answer below

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this problem, although in a less than efficient way.

In the eclipse.ini the location of the java.exe is specified. Usually the default location is fine but sometimes things can happen that causes this to not work and you need to specify the location of it. This is my laymans interpretation of what can be found here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

So to solve the problem I needed to change the default location in the .ini file to something that would work. I couldn't quite crack this though, so I downloaded a new version of the JDK and Eclipse, so that the default location will work again.

Eclipse is now running fine again.

Comment: Well done. You should accept this answer as the solution, so others can quickly find what worked.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following lines to eclipse.ini file solved my problem immediately:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe
```

I added these lines just before vmargs. It looks like as the following :

```
...
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

For more information on eclipse.ini, visit this the site http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Comment: `I added these lines just before vmargs.` It was necessary in my case. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me too. Make sure you point to your jdk for 32bit or 64 bit accordingly. Ex: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221 for 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the eclipse.ini file (in the eclipse directory) had the memory settings set too high and not enough memory was available (due to JBoss and Oracle running locally).

*My Settings:*

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
```

This was causing this same behavior.  In this case, either decreasing these memory settings (whatever they may be) or freeing up memory is the solution (the latter worked for me).

Comment: This helped me. In my ini I had the Xms with a higher value than the Xmx setting, which gives java more starting memory than the maximum it is allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename or delete the recent workspace suggestion file from here, then restart Eclipse

C:\eclipseNeon\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs